# Multilevel DropDown Menu With Scrollbar Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have multilevel dropdown with scrollbar. But it won't show 3level submenu.
Kindly suggest me on this.

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 80px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
       
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want submenu should start from top. Something like this https://ibb.co/jWeFwk, 
https://ibb.co/goO8Gk
kindly go through it & suggest me required changes in css.

Comment: Add your code to where i Stated `//Your code here` ...

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;

    /**
      * It's unnecessary.
      */
    /* overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    height: 80px; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the Updated Fiddle here : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kecahyk3/2/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="dropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-3">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    height: 120px;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu-3{
    height: 196px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Scroll is require to sub menus